# How to solve `TypeError: person.save is not a function` - what is wrong?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to save some data in mongodb database. So install mongoose node package to help me. And fallow the tutorial to do my best. But I got bellow error:

How to solve `TypeError: person.save is not a function` - what is wrong?

**Person Model:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        minLength: 3
    }
});

const Person = mongoose.model('person', personSchema);
module.exports = Person;
```

**Sever.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
let Person = require('./model/Person')

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABAS_URL,
{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, 
() => {
    console.log('DB Ok!')
})

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/add', async (req, res) => {
    const person = new Person({ name: req.body.name })
    console.log('/add route');
    console.log(req.body);
    try {
        console.log(`try`);
        const newPerson = await person.seve();
        res.json(newPerson);
        console.log(`end try:  ${newPerson}`)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({"err" : err});
        console.log(`catch: ${err}`);

    }
});


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server run on port ${PORT}`));
```

and here is my console:

```
Server run on port 3000
DB Ok!
/add route
{ name: 'Mohsen Rasouli'}
try
catch: TypeError: person.seve is not a function
```

and Postman App return:

```
{
    "err": {}
}
```

so... 
I don't now where is the problem and how can I solve it?
I'm new with express and mongoose.

Comment: `save()` not `seve()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use method `save` instead `seve`.

Answer (score 1):

```
const newPerson = await person.save();
```